# NullPointerException when focusing on EditText in AlertDialog

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, android-alertdialog

I've got a ListView where the cells/rows in that listView contains a button that presents an AlertDialog but when I tap the EditText to enter some text I get a NullPointerException when the ArrayAdapter's getView method returns.

I've tried 
***android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"*** & ***"beforeDescendants"*** on my ListView 
and added ***android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"*** which is what the similar topics has marked as correct answers but it's not working for me.

```
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(Menu.this);
        alert.setTitle(SubApp.pManager.getLanguageObject().getString("AddNoteToFavTitle"));
        final EditText input = new EditText(Menu.this);
        alert.setView(input);
        alert.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                saveInfoToPrefs(editor, id, input.getText().toString());
            }
        });
        alert.setNegativeButton(SubApp.pManager.getLanguageObject().getString("No"), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
                saveInfoToPrefs(editor, id, "");
            }
        });
        alert.show();
```

Does anyone know any other solution to this annoying issue?
Cheers!

Comment: First step is to look at your logcat and find out WHERE you get your NPE. Chances are, once you see that, you won't even have a question to ask ;)

Comment: Please show the adapter's code and the LogCat...